# Compare two Excel columns and if a match found paste the value of a third column into a fourth

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

If cell C2 value is in the range P2:P25 then paste the value in the matching row of Column T into the same row of Column N.

View [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2w_wM9f3gjoOXBPR0F0VFNvNDg/view?usp=sharing) for image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, written as a standalone example and assumes that data is on Sheet1 and transfers the first match.  Note that there is no error checking/handling in this example.

```
Sub xferNum()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim srow As Long, erow As Long, scol As Long, srchcol As Long
Dim rsltcol As Long, lucol As Long
Dim fndNo As Range, c As Range, lookrng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
srow = 2
scol = 3
srchcol = 16
lucol = 20
rsltcol = 14

    With ws
        erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, scol).End(xlUp).Row
        Set lookrng = .Range(.Cells(srow, scol), .Cells(erow, scol))
            For Each c In lookrng
                Set fndNo = Columns(srchcol).Find(what:=c.Value)
                    If Not fndNo Is Nothing Then
                        .Cells(c.Row, rsltcol).Value = fndNo.Offset(0, lucol - fndNo.Column).Value
                    End If
            Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In cell N2 put this formula: =IF(C2=P2, T2, "")

Then highlight cell N2 down to N25 and fill down. (CTRL + D).

Comment: doesnot solve my problem c2 is never equal to p2 instead c2 might be equal some where p2:p25 but don't know how to correspond T2 in N2 which will solve this problem

Comment: I recommend that you review your question and write it more clearly if you are looking for further assistance. It is not clear what you mean by "if C2 equals the value of "P2 to P25". Do you mean equal to any of the values?